# Datatable don't retain the newly added Object

Tags: jsf

what i am trying to do is, my List is mapped in datatable,
i have an add button, by clicking on it, i add an empty StudentVO in the datatable.
i maintain a counter cnt mapped to h:inputHidden, on click of the add button,

So i get input text in each column at the last row of the datatable,

but when i again click the Add button, my counter increments, but the datatable list don't have the newly added Student, what i get i two rows with empty input text

so again on the load of the page i get last row with input text whereas i am expecting  two rows, one row with input text which holds data entered previosly and a new row with empty input text,

this is following code,

```
public class StudentBeanThree {
    @Resource(name="jdbc/rahul_sample_pool",type=DataSource.class)
    private List<StudentVO> studentList;
    private Integer cnt;

    public List<StudentVO> getStudentList() {
       -----
    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
       try{
          loadStudents();
       }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

    private void loadStudents() throws Exception{
       //load student list
    }



public String addNewStudent(){
     // This method is called on click of the add button,
     if(getCnt() == null){
          setCnt(0);
     }

    this.cnt = getCnt();
    this.cnt++;
    this.setCnt(cnt);
    if(this.getStudentList() == null){
       loadStudents();
    }
    for(int x=0; x < getCnt().intValue();x++){
        this.getStudentList().add(new StudentVO());
    }   
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're preparing the data model in the action method instead of (post)constructor of the bean. It's then too late for JSF to update the data model with the submitted values. The data model is supposed to be finished before the *apply request values* phase, but in your case it's prepared during *invoke action* phase. You need to move the data model preparing job to bean's (post)constructor.

Based on your question history, you're using JSF 2.0. I would suggest a much simpler approach: put the bean in the view scope. It's then as simple as:

```html
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{students.list}" var="student">
        <h:column><h:inputText value="#{student.name}" /></h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    <h:commandButton value="Add" action="#{students.add}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{students.save}" />
</h:form>
```

and

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Students {

    private List<Student> list;

    @EJB
    private StudentService service;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        list = service.list();
    }

    public void add() {
        list.add(new Student());
    }

    public void save() {
        service.save(list);
    }

    public List<Student> getList() {
        return list;
    }

}
```

#### See also:

- [Benefits and pitfalls of `@ViewScoped`](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html)

Comment: but i my question i have already done @PostContruct to a method "init"